# How do I get rid of the symbol # in the header of the saved file?

Tags: python, numpy, format

Here is my code.

```
from numpy import savetxt
savetxt('a.txt',range(10),fmt="Number: %d",header='Index')
```

I want to make it like this:

```
Index
Number: 0
Number: 1
Number: 2
Number: 3
Number: 4
Number: 5
Number: 6
Number: 7
Number: 8
Number: 9
```

However, at the beginning of a.txt, there's a "#" and it looks as follows:

```
# Index
Number: 0
Number: 1
Number: 2
Number: 3
Number: 4
Number: 5
Number: 6
Number: 7
Number: 8
Number: 9
```

How to get rid of it (the sharp)? Did I use a wrong way to save an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the optional parameter `comments=''`:

```
savetxt('a.txt',range(10),fmt="Number: %d",header='Index',comments='')
```

See the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html). Simply look for the symbol `#` in the web page.